# A name for data distribution scheme

Tags: algorithm

I am looking for a concise name of data distribution scheme. Let's say we have 3 computers (`A, B, C`) and each of them can handle at most 2 units of data (we'll name the data units by `d1, d2, d3, d4`...).

Now, if we assume we have 5 units of data, and distribute them as follows: `d1, d4 -> A`, `d2, d5 -> B`, `d3 -> C` we would have been talking about round robin distribution.

What is the name of distribution that assumes that we use the smallest number of computers possible. For example, for 2 data units we would have: `d1, d2 -> A` and nothing for others, while for 5 it would be: `d1, d2 -> A`, `d3, d4 -> B`, `d5 -> C`. Is it called FIFO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Greedy distribution? You allocate as much as you can on each computer and move forward.